# How to implement iAds interstitial ads in Unity?

Tags: ios, iad, unity-game-engine

I have looked for some time now, and I have not found any answers anywhere and most posts I find are from 2008 and 2010. My question is, its there anyway to implement iAds interstitial ads on iPhones using Unity? I look all around, and even in the docs it says it only works on iPads but I have used them successfully before when I developed in Xcode. When I try to the do the same in Unity, Xcode just prints to the console `"ADInterstitialAd is not available. Must authenticate first"`

Any ideas on how to do it in Unity? If at all possible, or if this has been answered before could I pointed in the right direction?

Thanks!